# NiFi Cluster setup

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-zookeeper

Please help me to complete Nifi cluster setup. I can see Nifi is running on server, but GUI is not coming.

**Java version:**

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_302"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_302-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.302-b08, mixed mode)
```

**NiFi version:** nifi-1.17.0

**Nifi.properties:**

```
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start=true
nifi.remote.input.host=Svxxx.xyz.com
nifi.remote.input.secure=true
nifi.remote.input.socket.port=10443
nifi.remote.input.http.enabled=true
nifi.web.https.host=Svxxx.xyz.com
nifi.web.https.port=9443
nifi.web.proxy.host=localhost:9443,Svxxx.xyz.com:9443
nifi.sensitive.props.key=propkeywith12chars
nifi.cluster.is.node=true
nifi.cluster.node.address=Svxxx.xyz.com
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=11443
nifi.cluster.load.balance.host=Svxxx.xyz.com
nifi.cluster.load.balance.port=6342
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=Svxxx.xyz.com:2181,Svxxx.xyz.com:2181,Svxxx.xyz.com:2181
```

zookeeper. properties:

```
server.1=Svxxx.xyz.com:2888:3888;2181
server.2=Svxxx.xyz.com:2888:3888;2181
server.3=Svxxx.xyz.com:2888:3888;2181
```

**Changes made in state-management.xml:**

```
<cluster-provider>
<id>zk-provider</id>
<class>org.apache.nifi.controller.state.providers.zookeeper.ZooKeeperStateProvider</class>
<property name="Connect String">Svxxx.xyz.com:2181,Svxxx.xyz.com:2181,Svxxx.xyz.com:2181</property>
<property name="Root Node">/nifi</property>
<property name="Session Timeout">10 seconds</property>
<property name="Access Control">Open</property>
</cluster-provider>
```

**Firewall status:** disabled

Also created SSL certificate using toolkit, and put those on respective servers. Replaced truststore.jks and keystore.jks also accordingly.

**nifi-app.log:**

```
2022-10-17 22:00:05,669 WARN [main] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService There is currently no Cluster Coordinator. This often happens upon restart of NiFi when running an embedded ZooKeeper. Will register this node to become the active Cluster Coordinator and will attempt to connect to cluster again
2022-10-17 22:00:05,670 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.l.e.CuratorLeaderElectionManager CuratorLeaderElectionManager[stopped=false] Attempted to register Leader Election for role 'Cluster Coordinator' but this role is already registered
2022-10-17 22:00:11,403 WARN [Heartbeat Monitor Thread-1] o.a.n.c.l.e.CuratorLeaderElectionManager Unable to determine leader for role 'Cluster Coordinator'; returning null
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /nifi/leaders/Cluster Coordinator
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:102)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:2480)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:242)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:231)
        at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:93)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:228)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:219)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:41)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.locks.LockInternals.getSortedChildren(LockInternals.java:154)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.locks.LockInternals.getParticipantNodes(LockInternals.java:134)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.locks.InterProcessMutex.getParticipantNodes(InterProcessMutex.java:170)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.leader.LeaderSelector.getLeader(LeaderSelector.java:337)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.leader.election.CuratorLeaderElectionManager.getLeader(CuratorLeaderElectionManager.java:281)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.leader.election.CuratorLeaderElectionManager$ElectionListener.verifyLeader(CuratorLeaderElectionManager.java:571)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.leader.election.CuratorLeaderElectionManager$ElectionListener.isLeader(CuratorLeaderElectionManager.java:525)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.leader.election.CuratorLeaderElectionManager$LeaderRole.isLeader(CuratorLeaderElectionManager.java:466)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.leader.election.CuratorLeaderElectionManager.isLeader(CuratorLeaderElectionManager.java:262)
        at org.apache.nifi.cluster.coordination.node.NodeClusterCoordinator.isActiveClusterCoordinator(NodeClusterCoordinator.java:824)
        at org.apache.nifi.cluster.coordination.heartbeat.AbstractHeartbeatMonitor.monitorHeartbeats(AbstractHeartbeatMonitor.java:132)
        at org.apache.nifi.cluster.coordination.heartbeat.AbstractHeartbeatMonitor$1.run(AbstractHeartbeatMonitor.java:84)
        at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2022-10-17 22:00:12,371 INFO [Cleanup Archive for default] o.a.n.c.repository.FileSystemRepository Successfully deleted 0 files (0 bytes) from archive
2022-10-17 22:00:12,371 INFO [Cleanup Archive for default] o.a.n.c.repository.FileSystemRepository Archive cleanup completed for container default; will now allow writing to this container. Bytes used = 10.53 GB, bytes free = 26.46 GB, capacity = 36.99 GB
2022-10-17 22:00:14,203 INFO [Write-Ahead Local State Provider Maintenance] org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog@22e813fc checkpointed with 1 Records and 0 Swap Files in 5 milliseconds (Stop-the-world time = 2 milliseconds, Clear Edit Logs time = 2 millis), max Transaction ID 3
2022-10-17 22:00:18,823 WARN [main] o.a.n.c.l.e.CuratorLeaderElectionManager Unable to determine leader for role 'Cluster Coordinator'; returning null
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /nifi/leaders/Cluster Coordinator
```